# Minimum supported Gradle version is 7.2. Current version is 7.1

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

estoy desarrollando un plugin de flutter para android y cuando intento compilar mi gradle en android studio me avienta el sigiente error:

**Minimum supported Gradle version is 7.2. Current version is 7.1. Please fix the project's Gradle settings. Gradle Settings.**

Cuando actualizo la version de gradle esta me avienta el mismo error pero con la nueva version. Cuando cree el projecto este no me genero el grado wrapper.

Use los siguientes comando para crear el proyecto:

**fvm flutter create --template=plugin plugin-name**

**fvm flutter create -t plugin --platforms android .**

El siguiente codigo es lo que conteiene mi build.gradle:

```
group 'com.example.scan'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

rootProject.allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation files('src/libs/libscanner.jar')
}
```

Comment: intentaste cambiar la version del minSdkVersion a 21?

Comment: si, lo intente con la versión 21

Comment: Esto tiene que ver con la version de Gradle, no con la version minima de android o la que va dirigida la aplicacion.

Answer (score 0):

Desde el menú ve a `File` > `Project Structure` > `Project`, ahí puedes cambiar la versión de Gradle a `7.2` y si lo deseas también actualizar el plugin de Gradle:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagino que actualizaste Android Studio a la versión Chipmunk o posterior, por esta razón te requiere una nueva versión de Gradle.

Comment: A mi no me aparece esa opción de elegir la versión del gradle desde el apartado project structure / project. Tambien hice un downgrade de android studio a la versión artic fox y me sigue mostrando el mismo error y sin aparecer la opción de cambiar la versión del gradle.